# Vuetify button with loader continue in loading state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I made simple vuetify login form with button loader. But after sending POST request via axios the button doesn't return to normal state. It continues with loading state.

[image]

```
<v-btn color="primary" block x-large depressed :loading="loading" :disabled="loading" color="secondary" @click="submit">Sign In</v-btn>
```

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
        return {
            email: 'admin@example.com',
            password: '',
            loading: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.loading = true;
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: remote_url,
                data: {
                    username: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                }
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    this.loading = false;               
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    this.loading = false;                   
                });
        }
    }
})
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution would be:

```
this.loading = true;
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: remote_url,
  data: {
    username: this.email,
    password: this.password
  }
})
.then((response) => {            
  // response handler
})
.catch((error) => {
  // error handler
})
.finally(() => {
  this.loading = false;                   
});
```

Know that, if you use `function () {}`, your scope will change:

```
myFunction()
  .then(function () {
    // myfunction() scope
    // this = myFunction prototype
  })

myFunction()
  .then(() => {
    // stay in current scope
  })
```